# How to import a self-made module in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app` in my ReactJS app with TypeScript, and I would like to import a TypeScript/JavaScript module that I created in another project.

The module consists of a file `mymodule.js`, in which the code looks approximately like this:

```
var mymodule;
(function (mymodule) {
    var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
        function MyClass() {
        }
        MyClass.myMethod = function () {
            // code
        };
        return MyClass;
    }());
    mymodule.MyClass = MyClass;
})(mymodule || (mymodule = {}));
```

Then there is the type definition file `mymodule.d.ts`, which looks like this:

```
declare module mymodule {
    class MyClass {
        private static myMethod;
    }
}
```

In my `create-react-app` project, I placed these two files in the folder `/src/vendor`, and I want to use the module like this:

```
import { MyClass } from '../vendor/mymodule';

...
```

However, Visual Studio Code (i.e. the TypeScript compiler) says

```
File '.../vendor/mymodule.d.ts' is not a module. ts(2306)
```

When I run the project, the variables from the module (e.g. the class `MyClass`) are `undefined`.

This might be the reason for the error: The library is generated using `module: "AMD"`, but `create-react-app` seems to enforce `module: "esnext"`.

**Edit:** Here's the tsconfig.json of the `create-react-app` project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why don't you just copy paste the module into the new app and just use it as any other module ?

Comment: Can i have your tsconfig.json? do you include src/vendor ?

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé Isn't that what I'm doing? I'm copying the two files of the module to `src/vendor/mymodule`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't import the file due to the fact that you are not exporting the module.  In order for module loading to work, you should have an export at the bottom of your myModule class file.

```
export {
  mymodule
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this might be the reason. However, my module consists of more than one file (I'm using TypeScript's `--outFile` feature). Should I add these three lines at the end of all source files?

Comment: That just tells TypeScript to concatenate and emit output to single file.   I have to export explicitly in my TypeScript files.   As far as I know that statement has to be at the bottom of every file you want to be importable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with create-react-app but there is also this issue which you may have even after exporting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949876/create-react-app-typescript-does-not-load-d-ts-file'